# What's the total energy when I tie a mass with a string and then rotate it in a radius $r$ with angular velocity $\omega$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, string

I know it may be a very silly question. But when we are calculating the total energy, shouldn't we also consider the potential energy due to the centrifugal force acting on the body?
Or as, we are working in the inertial reference frame, we wouldn't add the potential energy term of the fictitious force...
Please someone clarify me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it depends on the reference frame. There are two obvious reference frames you can pick to work with here. The first is the "lab" observer who is watching you twirl the string from some inertial viewpoint. The other is of an observer who is riding on mass. This second one is noninertial frame, so things can be a little tricky, but it is still totally doable.

In the reference frame of the mass, it feels an outward centrifugal force due to the rotation, which for circular motion has magnitude $m\omega^2 r$. Note this is a conservative force, despite being noninertial. If you integrate this with the work equation
$$ W = - U_{\rm conservative} = \int \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$$
you can obtain an "effective potential energy" due to the centrifugal force.

However, in the lab frame, you need not do this. You can do normal $F=ma$ (or Lagrangian) type problem.

Answer (score 1):

Only conservative forces contribute potential energy, so there is no potential corresponding to the centrifugal pseudoforce. For the case of a mass on rotating string, the total energy is the sum of the linear kinetic energy and rotational kinetic energy, assuming gravitational and other potential energies are negligible.

Comment: +1. Great answer. It's funny how all the question, and the answers, including the accepted one, all had 0 votes! I looked at your profile and saw that you followed the Vexillology proposal. Would you consider committing to Materials Modeling? We only need a few more people to reach 100% and have the site launched: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=YzI2ZTk1NzM5MGNmODVkNjEwZTBhZjBjYWM4ZmM2MjM5ZTI5YWYwYTI5MTU2OTMzM2E0ODAxNzk4MTU4YTAyYn51ONsbLz_SLbfVYUbIF4bZ_RI3ArPPDQhylV6HyBZh0